# Difference between a loop in a function call and listing all the arguments explicitly

Tags: python, variadic-functions, generator-expression, argument-unpacking

I have a function that sorts a list of lists by the first list. When I use the function with the variables like so:

```
sort_lists(IN[0],IN[1],IN[2])
```

it works perfectly. Although, as I don't know how many lists my input contains, I want to use this as my variable:

```
sort_lists(IN[idx] for idx in range(len(IN)))
```

Although this returns a sorting of one list (the superlist). Why is there a difference between these variables, and how can I improve the code?

Here is the function if decisive (here IN[0] is the input with a number of sublists):

```
def sort_lists(*args):
    zipped_list= zip(*sorted(zip(*args)))
    return [list(l) for l in zipped_list]

OUT = sort_lists(data_sort[0],data_sort[1],data_sort[2])
```

I want to use this output:

```
OUT = sort_lists(data_sort[idx] for idx in range(len(IN[0])))
```

Comment: It’s the difference between arguments: `foo(a, b, c)` and one argument that’s a list: `foo([a, b, c])`. You’re already using `*args`, though – do you know what it does?

Comment: @Ry-
I know that *args enables me to have an ungiven number of arguments as my input. Although how do i use that in my output?

Comment: I am not completely sure what you try to do with your function. Can you provide an example for IN and the corresponding expected OUT? But as @Ry- already mentioned, the first time your are passing 3 separate lists, and the second time, you are basically giving a generator object as the lone argument to the function.

Comment: @DocDriven

What I wanna do (and am able to do now with a known number of inputs) is to sort a number of lists by the first list's sorting pattern. Say, I have an IN[0]=[2,4,3,1], and an in IN[1]=["two", "four", "three", "one"]. My output is OUT=[1,2,3,4],["one","two","three","four"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to understand here:

- `*args` will give you all function parameters [as a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)
- `IN[idx] for idx in range(len(IN))` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression)

You can see how your inputs are different if you simply add `print` statement in your function:

```
def sort_lists(*args):
    print(args)
    zipped_list= zip(*sorted(zip(*args)))
    return [list(l) for l in zipped_list]
```

Let the input list of lists be: `lists = [[2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 4], [5, 4, 2]]`.

```
sort_lists(lists[0], lists[1], lists[2])
```

will print: `([2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 4], [5, 4, 2])`. That's a tuple of inner lists.

Though, if you call it like this:

```
sort_lists(lists[idx] for idx in range(len(lists)))
```

or

```
sort_lists(sublist for sublist in lists)
```

this will print `(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000007001D3FBA0>,)`, a one-element tuple of a generator.

You can make your function work with a generator by accepting only one parameter:

```
def sort_lists(arg):
    zipped_list= zip(*sorted(zip(*arg)))
    return [list(l) for l in zipped_list]

sort_lists(lists[idx] for idx in range(len(lists)))
# [[1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 4], [4, 5, 2]]
```

but I suggest to leave your function as is, and [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) your lists in the place where you call it instead:

```
>>> sort_lists(*lists)
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 4], [4, 5, 2]]
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for the answer! I just unpacked my lists in the output and it works as I wanted it to now.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the function to accept list of lists, is it problem? This piece of code:

> ```
> IN[idx] for idx in range(len(IN))
> ```

returns again list of lists

Comment: How would you do that? Apologies but I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

As Georgy pointed out, the difference is between the arguments being a generator or list. I would also like to point out that this is an opportunity to use and practice the `map` method. `map` applies the same function to each entry in a list. The function can be a built-in like `sorted`.

```
list_a = [[2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 4], [5, 4, 2]]
sorted_list_a = list(map(sorted, list_a)) # sorted is the python built-in function
print(sorted_list_a)
```

Returns:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 5]]
```

You'll notice that you'll have to pass your `map` to the `list` function because `map` returns a map object, so you have to turn it into a list.

The [map documentation is here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). And a [good example of it is here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html).